# How do i map this url

Tags: regex, google-app-engine

I am using google appengine and cant map this URL "user/test@example.com"

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication( [('/user/(\w+)',UsersSubPath)],debug=True)
```

I dont know why this expression doesnt work. any ideas?

Comment: What URL doesn't work?  It will match `/user/1` but if you want to match `/user/` it should be `'/user/(\w*)'`.  BTW, I think booleans are case sensitive: `debug=True`.

Comment: my bad... forgot the URL. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to widen the scope of your regex.  `\w` only matches `[A-Za-z0-9]` which excludes the special characters `@` and `.`.  For this example you could use:

```
'/user/([A-Za-z0-9@.]*)'
```

or

```
'/user/(\S*)'
```

Comment: it gives me this error   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 634, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
TypeError: get() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
Thank you

Comment: How is your get defined under `class UsersSubPath...`?  `def get(self, email)` or similar?

Comment: class UsersSubPath(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self): #/user/username
        TheName = str(self.request.path[6:]).replace('%40', '@')        is that abnormal? Thank you

Comment: The regex capture in parenthesis - `'([A-Za-z0-9@.]*)'` is your second argument.  Try the `def get` I used above and the `email` argument will have your email.

Comment: BTW, I meant to use the more restrictive `+` instead of `*`.

Comment: Thanx, it works, yet I dont know how. Where can I find the API of the "get" or how come the regex capture is the second argument? Thank you

Comment: A `get()` should have `self` as the 1st argument.  You can see [here under URL Mappings](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/running.html) where the URL has 2 groups, `(.*)` and a second `(.*)`.  Any URL that matches that expression will pass whatever matches in those groups as the 1st and 2nd parameter.